# Is my getStatement method thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, guava, concurrenthashmap

I have a below Singleton class where in my `getStatement` method, I populate a CHM by doing if check.

```
public class CacheHolder {
  private static final Map<String, PreparedStatement> holder = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  private static class Holder {
    private static final CacheHolder INSTANCE = new CacheHolder();
  }

  public static CacheHolder getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private CacheHolder() {}

  public BoundStatement getStatement(String cql) {
    Session session = TestUtils.getInstance().getSession();
    PreparedStatement ps = holder.get(cql);
    if (ps == null) {
      ps = session.prepare(cql);
      holder.put(cql, ps);
    }
    return ps.bind();
  }
}
```

Is my `getStatement` method thread safe?

Comment: I would recommend using a [Guava cache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) instead of CHM, because it comes with atomic "get-if-absent-compute" semantics, which is what you want here.

Comment: What are `PreparedStatement` and `BoundStatement`? In the javadoc, I don't see any `bind` method, so it's not `java.sql.PreparedStatement`. Why is this important? Because it's important to know if the final object itself is thread-safe. If it is, then good, but if it is not, then you have a problem because you make sure that creating it is thread-safe, but your object itself isn't? Hmmm... Not sure I prefer that...

Comment: I am working with Cassandra so I have to re-use prepared statements and that's why I am caching it here. [Prepared Statement](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/da72105c2fcef8f0865047815df146cfbb2354e6/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/PreparedStatement.java) and [BoundStatement](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/da72105c2fcef8f0865047815df146cfbb2354e6/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/BoundStatement.java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer provided by @javaguy is right, but just a small optimization to ensure synchronized block doesn't get executed for every thread when its not needed.

```
public static BoundStatement getStatement(String cql) {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Session session = null;
    try {
      session = TestUtils.getInstance().getSession();
      PreparedStatement ps = holder.get(cql);
      if(ps == null) { // If PS is already present in cache, then we don't have to synchronize and make threads wait.
        synchronized {
          ps = holder.get(cql);
          if (ps == null) {
            ps = session.prepare(cql);
            holder.put(cql, ps);
          }
        }
      }
    } finally {
        //release the resources
    }
    return ps.bind();
  }
```

You can also use [Guava Cache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) or if you want a Map then [Guava MapMaker](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html).

**Using Guava Cache:**

```
LoadingCache<String, PreparedStatement> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .maximumSize(1000)
       .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       .build(
           new CacheLoader<String, PreparedStatement>() {
             public PreparedStatement load(String cql) throws Exception {
               return createPreparedStatement(cql);
             }
           });
```

**Using Map Maker :**

```
ConcurrentMap<String, PreparedStatement> cache = new MapMaker()
       .concurrencyLevel(32)
       .weakValues()
       .makeComputingMap(
           new Function<String, PreparedStatement>() {
             public PreparedStatement apply(String cql) {
               return createPreparedStatement(cql);
             }
           });
```

Also, I would suggest not to **cache PreparedStatement's** as these **resources need to released** AFAIK.

Comment: How about using `putIfAbsent` method here instead of using synchronized block?

Comment: No, It wouldn't make much difference. `putIfAbsent` will ensure that when 2 threads are trying to write the same key, only one of the values will go ahead and the other thread which tried to write would fail insertion and would return the value that was put by thread1.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the answer from @Bandi Kishore as it is more efficient than the below one (The below answer requires `synchronization` for each call to `getStatement()` which can be avoided by adding one more `null` check).

> Is my getStatement method thread safe?

No, it is NOT threadsafe, in your `getStatement(String cql)` method, you are doing a **`null` check with race condition** which is popularly known as **double checked locking**, you can look [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/LCK10-J.+Use+a+correct+form+of+the+double-checked+locking+idiom) on this. i.e., There is a race condition in your code while the threads are executing `holder.get(cql);` and you need to `synchronize` the critical section of that code as shown below:

```
public static BoundStatement getStatement(String cql) {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Session session = null;
    try {
      session = TestUtils.getInstance().getSession();
      synchronized {
        PreparedStatement ps = holder.get(cql);
        if (ps == null) {
          ps = session.prepare(cql);
          holder.put(cql, ps);
       }
    }
    } finally {
        //release the resources
    }
    return ps.bind();
  }
```

Also, as a side note, ensure that you are releasing the resources.

Comment: No, it does not, basically there is a race condition, not caching issue (volatile solves only caching issue between threads)